# ContextCompat.getDrawable not working on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am using ContextCompat (v4 support library version) to programatically fetch drawables in my code. It is working fine on all the android versions except Marshmallow. I mean images are not showing up on screen in android M. Here is the code I am using:

```
Drawable myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.id);
myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.6), (int) (myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.6));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(myDrawable, 0, -1, -1);
mToggleButton.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working?

Comment: @Jared image is not showing up on screen in Marshmallow

Comment: when calling `setCompoundDrawables` why do you use `sd.getDrawable()` and not `sd` ?

Comment: @pksink because I need to show the drawable. Moreover using sd instead of sd.getDrawable() does not solve the problem either.

Comment: ok so you are saying that `ContextCompat#getDrawable` is not working, then use `Resource#getDrawable` instead

Comment: @pksink Resource#getDrawable is deprecated in Lollipop and above. So cant use that either.

Comment: no its not: see all the versions `(This method was deprecated in API level 22.
Use getDrawable(int, Theme) instead.)`

Comment: @pskink sorry I read that wrong, getResources.getDrawable(int, Theme) works for API level 21 and above. I tried using it on android M but the image still won't show up. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any documentation, but setProgressDrawable only worked when it was called before setLayoutParams.  This code is from a CursorAdapter.

This worked:

```
ProgressBar progressBar3 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        if(numScoreValues == 4){
        progressBar3.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.progress_green));
        }
        progressBar3.setMax(totalTargets);
        progressBar3.setProgress(userResultArray[3]);
        progressBar3.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This did not work. The progress bar had no background.

```
  ProgressBar progressBar3 = (ProgressBar)              view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);

        progressBar3.setMax(totalTargets);
        progressBar3.setProgress(userResultArray[3]);
        progressBar3.setLayoutParams(params);
if(numScoreValues == 4){
                progressBar3.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.progress_green));
        }
```